# MySQL - SUM of ALIAS not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

ORIGINAL TABLE

```
   TAG 1 |  TAG 2  | TAG 3  | DATE OF REQUEST | RSP_CODE | ERROR | VALUE  |

     1   |   A    |  99    | 29/10/2019      |    00    |   2   | 10.25  |
     2   |   A    |  99    | 28/10/2019      |    55    |   0   | 50.99  |
     1   |   A    |  99    | 28/10/2019      |    99    |   0   | 100.00 |
     3   |   B    |  99    | 27/10/2019      |    10    |   2   | 30.00  |
     2   |   C    |  99    | 29/10/2019      |    00    |   0   | 45.00  |
```

EXPECTED TABLE

```
   ID |  A   |  B    |  C    |  D    |  E    |  F    |  G    |  H  |

 29_10_2019_1_A_99 |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |CURRENCY |
 29_10_2019_2_B_99   |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |CURRENCY |
 29_10_2019_3_C_88   |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |NUMBER |CURRENCY |
```

**Name of Column**  - **Expected value**

**ID** - CONCATENATION OF DAY_MONTH_YEAH_TAG1_TAG2_TAG3

**A** - COUNT OF RSP_CODE '00' AND THAT THE ERROR **IS NOT 2**

**B** - COUNT OF RSP_CODE THAT **ARE NOT '00'** AND THAT THE ERROR **IS NOT 2**

**C** - COUNT OF RSP_CODE THAT ARE '00' AND THAT ERROR IS 2

**D** - COUNT OF RSP_CODE THAT **ARE NOT '00'** AND THAT THE ERROR IS 2

**E** - SUM OF VALUES THAT ARE RSP_CODE = '00' AND THAT ERROR **IS NOT 2**

**F** - SUM OF VALUES THAT **ARE NOT RSP_CODE '00'** THAT THE ERROR **IS NOT 2**

**G** - SUM OF VALUES THAT ARE RSP_CODE = '00' AND THAT ERROR IS '2'

**H** - SUM OF VALUES THAT **ARE NOT RSP_CODE '00'** AND THAT THE ERROR IS '2'

Comment: No. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to aliases in the same `SELECT` list. You need to put the query into a subquery.

```
SELECT col0, 
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8,
        col1+col2+col3+col4 AS total1,
        col5+col6+col7+col8 AS total2
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(extract(day from datetime_req),"_",extract(month from datetime_req),"_",
                extract(year from datetime_req),"_",`card_acceptor_id_code`,"_",`terminal_id`,"_",`ext_nserie_simcard`,"_",`ext_connection_type`) AS 'col0',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN `rsp_code_rsp` = '00' AND `tran_reversed` = '0'  THEN 'APROVADA EFETIVADA' END)  AS 'Col1',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN `rsp_code_rsp` != '00' AND `tran_reversed` = '0'  THEN 'NEGADA EFETIVADA'  END)  AS 'Col2',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN `rsp_code_rsp` = '00' AND `tran_reversed` != '0'  THEN 'APROVADA DESFEITA' END)  AS 'Col3',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN `rsp_code_rsp` != '00' AND `tran_reversed` != '0'  THEN 'NEGADA DESFEITA'  END)  AS 'Col4',
        SUM(CASE WHEN `rsp_code_rsp` = '00' AND `tran_reversed` = '0'  THEN `tran_amount_req` ELSE 0 END)/100 AS 'col5',
        SUM(CASE WHEN  `rsp_code_rsp` != '00' AND `tran_reversed` = '0'  THEN `tran_amount_req` ELSE 0 END)/100 AS 'col6',
        SUM(CASE WHEN `rsp_code_rsp` = '00' AND `tran_reversed` != '0'  THEN `tran_amount_req` ELSE 0 END)/100 AS 'Col7',
        SUM(CASE WHEN  `rsp_code_rsp` != '00' AND `tran_reversed` != '0'  THEN `tran_amount_req` ELSE 0 END)/100 AS 'Col8'
    FROM `table`  
    WHERE `datetime_req` BETWEEN '2019-10-29 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-29 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY col0
) AS x
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, however the sum returns both values as zero :(, and i need that the sum columns to be in the same table as well. This query returns a table with 3 columns, my expectation was to get a table containing the other columns as well as the examble below:

col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | total1 | total2

Comment: Thank you for your Help Barman, i guess it improved the output, but the columns are not showing the values, they are only showing me the name of the columns as values and the sum column are still as zero. any ideia?

Comment: If you're getting zeroes then the conditions in the `CASE` expressions are never matching.

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data and desired results? Please post it as plain text so I can copy it for testing.

Comment: i updated the post. :) Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: Why do you have the words `NUMBER` instead of the actual numbers? And why did you remove your original code?

Comment: Your original query has columns `rsp_code_rsp`, `tran_reversed`, and `tran_amount_request`, `card_acceptor_id_code`, `terminal_id`, `ext_nserie_simcard`, `ext_connection_type`. Where are these in the updated question?

Comment: Hi Barman, sorry for the confusion, i discovered the issue, the problem was that i used ''(single quotes) for the name of the columns, so the field was being interpreted as string. I removed them and the code worked as you mentioned before. Thank you very much!!